# "glUniform1fARB"?

Tags: opengl, glsl

What dose `glUniform1fARB` do?

is there any detailed online reference materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [this google (OpenGL reference) result](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/)?

Note that the base name for such methods is `glUniform`, so look for that. `1f` means one float parameter, `ARB` means the method is common but not part of core OpenGL as of some version. I'm not sure in which exact version the function was promoted, but I assume it was something around `3.0`, and thus you'd now just use `glUniform1f`.

Edit: The spec sais promotion happend in 2.0: "glUniform is available only if the GL version is 2.0 or greater."

Comment: If I just use `glUniform1f` , I get `Error 11 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glUniform1f referenced in function _updateAnim ogl2particle.obj fire` and `Error 12 fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals d:\2011s1\cs9018\vs2008workspace\GLSL_fire\fire\Debug\firedebug.exe fire`

Comment: Which OpenGL version does your driver support? From your error I assume you use Windows. You should use [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GLEE](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/) to check the OpenGL version and link the extensions or newer core functions.

Comment: "If I just use glUniform1f , I get..." - Well, yes. As I said, this depends on the OpenGL version. If you don't have support for a version where glUniform was promoted to core you'd still have to use the `...ARB` version. However, the functionality is still the same.

Comment: Just looking at the spec, where it saos "glUniform is available only if the GL version is 2.0 or greater." - Thus for OpenGL 1.x you'd only have the ...ARB version.